# Using sinon to stub String.prototype getter method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a scenario where I need to stub a getter method on `String.prototype`. In this case a method defined by the NPM module `colors`.

```
it('should only apply colors if enable in the .ENV file', function () {
    var stringGreyStub = sinon.stub(String.prototype, 'grey').get(function(){
        console.log('FAKE!');
    });
    Log.setLevel(1);
    Log.log('Message to log.', 1);
    console.log(stringGreyStub.called);
});
```

The output of the above test is:

```
FAKE!
[28/Sep/2017:08:06:13-0700] This is some message to be logged!
false
```

It appears as far as I can tell the stub is being called because `FAKE!` is being logged. However the value of `stringGreyStub.called` is still `false`. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to just be the way that sinon functions when it comes to getters and setters. The solution is to use a stub for the actual getter value and check if that is called.

```
it('should only apply colors if enable in the .ENV file', function () {
    var getterStub = sinon.stub();
    sinon.stub(String.prototype, 'grey').get(getterStub);
    Log.setLevel(1);
    Log.log('Message to log.', 1);
    console.log(getterStub.called);
});
```

The solution was found in the following github issue.

https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1545

Comment: How do you restore the stub? When I try:
`getterStub.restore()`, I get the error: "TypeError: getterStub.restore is not a function"